# Storing data securely with Go and Compute Engine

Tags: security, go

I have a small package written in Go that logs into a financial institution and aggregates some data that I require for research purposes. However, to login to the institution requires a username, password, and pin that I would rather not have stored in the cloud (this will run atop Compute Engine). Since cookies expire every one hour (and the script will run once per day) the program will require the login details frequently (in other words I can't just pass them manually when the instance first starts). So I need a method to either store or have the program access the details securely while running in Compute Engine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe this can give you a starting point? http://security.stackexchange.com/q/61627

Comment: While I upvoted @VonC's comment, I would also like to clarify a little.  Basically the solution being recommended is to store the passwords in an encrypted file and then pass in the password to decrypt that file at run time